# Cleveref and polyglossia problems with crefname

Tags: luatex, cleveref, polyglossia

I am having problems with polyglossia and cleveref.

The following snippet works as intended:

```
\documentclass{book}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setdefaultlanguage[variant=us]{english}

\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\Crefname{chapter}{Chapter}{Chapters}
\crefname{chapter}{Ch.}{Chs.}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\Cref{ch:a}\\
    \cref{ch:a} 
\chapter{title}\label{ch:a}

\end{document}
```

and gives [image]

However, uncommenting polyglossia commands as given above yields:

[image]

---

I am using TL 2019 (latest packages) with lualatex.

Comment: There is a whole section in the `cleveref` manual devoted to the interplay of cleveref, polyglossia and babel. If you don't want that the chosen language has an effect on cleveref you has to load `cleveref` before `polyglossia`

Comment: @user1146332 thanks for the hint. But for some reason, downgrading polyglossia makes it work again. Maybe a bug?

Comment: no problem here, I got the expect behavior (as in the first fig) !!!! may be I'm not using the latest patches (`LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux) LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 1`)

Comment: @hkh I believe the latest version of all packages brings the problem... `sudo tlmgr --all update` will update all I guess

Comment: @bonanza Maybe the bug is in the downgraded version. According to the manual it's wanted that polyglossia overwrites the cross-reference naming scheme.

Comment: I experience the exact same problem as the OP does on a Mac, MacTeX2020 (prerelease version), `polyglossia 2020/03/25 v1.48`. Switching to `babel` is no problem, by the way.

Comment: @user1146332 polyglossia revision `50787` does not have that problem in my case (that is the version I downgraded to) but it brings other problems for me, so its not a solution for me.

Comment: I do not use `tlmgr` just `sudo pacman -Syu`, however I did not update to 2019.51075-8 (istill on texlive-bin=2019.51075-6)

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with a fully updated MikTeX system (`polyglossia.sty 2020/03/25 v1.48`, `cleveref.sty 2018/03/27 v0.21.4`).

Comment: @hkh Your LaTeX version is definitely outdated, possibly some of the packages relevant here (`polyglossia`, `cleveref`) are not up to date either. If this was caused by a recent `polyglossia` change that could explain why you don't see the issue.

Comment: Even though it is quite likely that the issue was brought to light by the `polyglossia` update, you may still want to contact the `cleveref` developer about this. `polyglossia` got a much nicer package author interface recently, and the `cleveref` developer may well want to hear about and make us of it.

Comment: @moewe, thanks, I contacted the cleveref dev/maintainer.

Comment: that never worked properly. As soon as there is a selectlanguage, the crefname is reset even in older versions: `\cref{ch:a}\selectlanguage{english}\cref{ch:a} `.

Comment: any idea? the only way I have found is to redifine crefformat and so on, but that is not practical.